# Java SOAP client stub generation with service endpoint determined at runtime

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, stub

Previously, I've written SOAP clients in Python and used the SUDS library.  Without getting into the details, the "stub" generation is really quite dynamic as it's done at runtime and, with Python being so typeless, I'm able to reference the expected methods generated by the WSDL without a pre-compiled stub.  I'm fine with generating a stub with something like wsimport, because it's great to have the composition of SOAP messages being handled via a nice Java object structure.  So, I'm not looking for a dynamic generation mechanism akin to SUDS in python.

My problem is that all the simple JAX-WS examples I see are for what I'll call a "statically located web service".  What I'm trying to do is connect to a web service with a known WSDL from which I could generate stubs at compile time but whose location is only known at runtime.  For example, say I want to access Microsoft SharePoint Web Services.  Wherever my application is deployed, there will a different SharePoint server (or servers) running which will need to be specified at runtime.  All the simple examples I've seen have the service location URL hard-coded into the stubs through wsimport.  Is there a way to generate stubs but supply the service location at runtime?

I'm really surprised not to find any examples of this because I figure what I'm trying to do should be very common as Web Services go.  Perhaps the answer is that I can't be lazy and get a nice objectified version of the WSDL methods if the server location is only known at runtime.  I've seen SAAJ examples but there, of course, I have to generate the SOAP messages by hand myself.  That would be such a shame when the WSDL is known at compile time.  Can't I have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: I considered answering my own question but I'm still investigating "Dynamic Proxy".  So far, it looks like exactly what I'm describing above.  I'm still not clear on how the dynamic stubs differ from the static stubs since it looks like wsimport is used for both.  Anyone with experience using Dynamic Proxy would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want to connect to multiple web services that expose the same WSDL but are located at different addresses and your client contains only the address of the service used to generate it?

In that case have a look at this post: [Changing WSDL url (endpoint) in JAX-WS client](http://biemond.blogspot.ro/2009/04/changing-wsdl-url-endpoint-in-jax-ws.html).

Comment: Exactly right, thank you very much @Bogdan!  The "other and better way" is precisely what I was looking for.  Looking at that example, I dug into my simple sample that I had generated with wsimport and saw that, indeed, it generates multiple constructors for the Service object which I hadn't noticed before.  The default constructor uses the URL used to generate the stubs but there is a constructor to which you can pass the URL of the new endpoint WSDL specified at runtime.  Again, much thanks!