# Dynamic @WebServiceRef wsdlLocation when packaging a war

Tags: java, web-services, dynamic, annotations, maven-profiles

I am using

```
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/test/test?wsdl")
```

to specify a wsdl location, also I use maven profiles and some have a different wsdl Location.

I know that annotations can't be changed dynamically, but is there a way to select a right wsdl location when packaging a war?(it is external, I can't just put wsdl file in profile folder to make maven select right one).

I was thinking of creating some sort of file, where that name will be specified (not config file, that won't work) and just adding that file as wsdllocation, but I'm not sure if that's right/what kind of file that should be.

Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: See if these can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306203 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703195

Comment: second one was really helpful, thanks a lot!